# Should we accept? Split wood/too dark inlay in floor installation

Tags: wood, flooring, hardwood-floor, installation

we recently had our floors refinished/installed. In our kitchen, the old linoleum was ripped out, and we had hardwood floors installed to match the rest of the house. The house has an accent inlay in the floors- [see here](https://imgur.com/a/D7XszNe). We asked that they match the inlay in the kitchen. When we went back after they installed to see what it looked like, almost all the inlay showed splitting where it was nailed in and was a noticeably darker color-[see here](https://imgur.com/gallery/dovsyt1). Is this a product of shoddy installation? Or is this to be expected due to the nature of matching color/installing the inlay?

[image]

<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

[image]

<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

Comment: I'm no expert on installing wood floors, but I would not accept that work.

Comment: I would absolutely not accept that. The color isn't even remotely close and the splitting is pretty outrageous, something that could cause issues in the future. They could have glued it and used 23g nail to hold it until the glue set.

Comment: Colour matching can be hard to do(fading/age).  The splitting is just bad work.

Comment: What they said. Color is hard, but the splitting is sheer incompetence.

Comment: Splits are 100% unacceptable. The split would crack the protective layer and those boards will start absorbing moisture immediately. The entire floor won't last more than a few years tops. Significantly worse if you are in a humid area, or spill water on it.

Comment: Gotta love the tan nail hole filler on the dark sections, and the generally poorly-filled-in nail holes.

Comment: There is a vote to close as being opinion based.  Colour matching maybe, but teh splitting isnt, so voting it to leave it open